# Is there a way to replicate the look of Allen-Khondji Midnight in Paris and To Rome With Love?

Tags: photo-editing, filters, light

I was wondering is there a way to achieve the look of Woody Allen's films *Midnight in Paris* and *To Rome With Love*, for which the director of photography was the Iranian-French cinematographer Darius Khondji?

Some of the aspects of the looks, which differ to a certain amount, in my view, are often the early-morning or late-afternoon sunlight, at other times cloudy weather, diffused light, yellowish cast to the *Midnight in Paris* images and very warm, sometimes "extreme" (to quote Darious Khondji himself) orangish, ochre colour of *To Rome With Love*, then those imperial reds of Fouquet's awnings or the emerald ones of Quai de la Mégisserie flower shop, backlighting.

I would like to know what are some of the tools and techniques one can use to get close to achieving this look?

I'm interested in if one should use filters, and if yes, which ones; should one pick a custom white balance in-camera or change it in postproduction; are there any specific things one should do to contrast, vibrance, saturation, tone curves, HSL curves; should one use split toning; and anything else that comes to mind that you can share.

Obviously, both films were expensive productions using very specialized equipment, such as custom-made inflatable mattresses, used together with large canvas rugs to cut and diffuse the harsh summer light, but the point is to find out if there are alternative ways to achieve the looks.

Comment: Here are some screencaps of the two films: http://www.thecinetourist.net/an-american-tourist-in-paris.html and http://movie-tourist.blogspot.com/2013/01/to-rome-with-love-2012.html.

Comment: Are you talking about replicating the looks in still photos or in video/motion pictures? Video/motion pictures are off topic here.

Comment: White balance, tone, contrast, saturation, split toning, etc all apply to still photography, so would be on-topic here.

Comment: Michael, I'm talking about stills, of course. As MikeW points out, I think that is visible from the terms used.

Comment: WB, tone, contrast, saturation, etc. are very different when taking stills and saving as RAW files than when shooting video where typically jpeg type compression is already applied to each frame before saving the file.

Comment: I know. Would you know how to replicate the look?

Answer (score -1):

You are most likely looking for "Cross-Processing."

You can find many plug-ins that should replicate the effect.  You can also grab a freebie that should do what you want from ["Perfect Effects"](http://www.on1.com/products/effects9free/).

Comment: Hoham, which of the effects you think could approximate the look of the two films?